# UICollectionView and Core Data performance tuning

Tags: ios, core-data, uicollectionview, restkit

I am trying to optimise my `UICollectionView` performance. Here is the setup:

- the `UICollectionView` gets its data from Core Data. Objects are retrieved from the back end with `RestKit`
- the app gets big chunks of JSON data from the backend. The JSON is stored "as is" and not mapped into objects automatically (too expensive).
- when a cell needs its data, the following happens:

  - fetch the corresponding object from `CoreData`
  - if not loaded yet, then find the corresponding JSON data and map it into Core Data

It works fine. But the problem is if the user starts scrolling really fast, the UI lags because of the Core Data fetches and RestKit mapping operations.

One of the obvious issues with my setup is that I could not use a `NSFetchedResultsController`. Indeed, my fetch request is not a "standard" Core Data one. It needs the "fall back" to JSON-mapping mechanism. As a consequence, the Core Data requests are not batched.

Hence my questions:

- is there a way to build a `NSFetchRequest` with a "fallback" mechanism as described above?
- if you can't use a `NSFetchedResultsController`, what's the recommended strategy to batch cells updates?

Comment: Surely it is better to do the 'expensive' mapping earlier and in the background rather than on demand from the user...

Comment: @Wain I don't know... We are talking thousands of objects (that's how the external API works), and maybe the user will only end up seeing a dozen. It seems to me it makes sense to try and map on demand. From my tests, the mapping operation is quite expensive.

Comment: @Wain I should add: I tried to load/map in the background, but since I can't ask the user to wait I also had to do it on demand in the main thread for visible objects. I ended up with loads of concurrency (I think) issues. Maybe I was doing it wrong but mixing background and main thread mapping of the same objects seemed complicated.

Comment: Well, RestKit isn't going to get you the most speed possible. And you give no details of your core data batching (use instruments to check operation). See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877171/coredata-and-restkit-performance-while-importing-very-large-datasets